# Get documents if they exist and insert them and return the insert document in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document

I have a list of students as the following in my MongoDB database `["student1", "student2", "student3"]` and I am trying to run a query where I have another list `["student5", "student2", "student7"]`. Given that I already have `"student2"` I do not want to update it. I just want to insert `student5", and "student7"`. After insertion, I want to return the document of all the students `["student5", "student2", "student7"]`. Is it possible to do so using Mongoose?
The schema look like the following:

```js
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: [true, 'Please provide an Email!'],
    unique: [true, 'Email already exists'],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: [true, 'Please provide a Password!'],
    unique: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: [true, 'Please provide a name!'],
    unique: false,
  },
  residency: {
    type: String,
    require: false,
    unique: false,
  },
  
  gpa: {
    type: number,
    require: false,
    unique: false,
  },
});
```

in my database I have the following students

```js
{
  _id:######,
  name: "student1",
  email: "email",
  password:"password",
  residency:null,
  gpa: 3.9,
},
{
  _id:####,
  name: "student2",
  email: "email",
  password:"password",
  residency:null,
  gpa: 2.5,
},
{
  _id:##########,
  name: "student3",
  email: "email",
  password:"password",
  residency:null,
  gpa: 3.4,
}
```

the query I ran

```js
db.students.updateOne({ name: { $in: ["student2", "student5", "student7"]}, { $addToSet: { students: { $each: [{
      name: "student2",
      email: "email",
      password:"password",
      residency:"class 1",
      gpa: 3.9,
    },{
      name: "student5",
      email: "email",
      password:"password",
      residency:"class 13",
      gpa: 3.00,
    },{
      name: "student7",
      email: "email",
      password:"password",
      residency:"class 10",
      gpa: 2.00,
    }]}}}, {new: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert many documents without overriding the existing ones, you need to specify the unique key index (in your case it's `name` I guess) and then perform the `insertMany` operation with `ordered: false` parameter and catch the duplicate key exception. You could read about unordered inserts here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts

```js
try {
    db.students.insertMany([{
        name: "student2",
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
        residency: "class 1",
        gpa: 3.9,
    }, {
        name: "student5",
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
        residency: "class 13",
        gpa: 3.00,
    }, {
        name: "student7",
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
        residency: "class 10",
        gpa: 2.00,
    }], { ordered: false })
} catch (err) { //treat the err }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Unless I am missing something, addToset will allow me to update it. I want to return the inserted and existing values as well. Will I need to run a separate query for that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to pass `new` param of true in the options object

Comment: I tried running the following query `db.students.updateOne({ name: { $in: ["student2", "student5", "student7"]}, { $addToSet: { students: { $each: [ "student2", "student5", "student7" ] } } },
   { new: true })`  and the result is that just creates another field on the first student name whose name is in the list with the data I just added. However, I want new students to be added to the main collection

Comment: The result looks like this `{_id: objectId(), name: "student2", students:["student2", "student5", "student7" ]}`

Comment: Could you please update your question with the collection schema? It's a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated post to add the schema, what I have in my database and the query I ran

Comment: Thanks, I am guessing will need to run a separate find query to get the data after the insertion. I was trying to do both on the same query

Comment: Bear in mind that the result might be inconsistent because your data may be changed between these two queries.